# prevent query from return duplicate results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database contains information for a telecommunication company with the following table:

- `SUBSCRIBERS (SUB_ID , F_NAME , L_NANE , DATE_OF_BIRTH , COUNTRY)`
- `LINES (LINE_ID , LINE_NUMBER)`
- `SUBSCRIBERS_LINES (SUB_LINE_ID , SUB_ID "foreign key", LINE_ID "foreign key", ACTIVATION_DATE)`
- `CALLS (CALL_ID , LINE_FROM "foreign key", LINE_TO "foreign key" , START_DATE_CALL, END_DATE_CALL)`

I want to retrieve the names of top 3 subscribers who make the highest count number of calls (with duration less than 60 seconds for each call) in specific given day.

So, I write the following query :

```
with TEMPRESULT AS 
(
    select * from 
    (
      select CALLS.LINE_FROM , count(*) totalcount
      from CALLS
      where (((END_DATE_CALL-START_DATE_DATE)*24*60*60)<=60 and to_char(S_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')='2015-12-12') 
      group by CALLS.LINE_FROM
      order by totalcount DESC
    ) 
    where rownum <= 3
) 

select F_NAME,L_NAME
from TEMPRESULT inner join SUBSCRIBERS_LINES on TEMPRESULT.LINE_FROM=SUBSCRIBERS_LINES.line_id inner join SUBSCRIBERS on SUBSCRIBERS_LINES.SUB_ID=SUBSCRIBERS.SUB_ID;
```

But this query will not work if one of the subscribers has more than one line,

for example:
(`X1` has `L1` and `L2` lines

`X2` has `L3`

`X3` has `L4`)

**if** `X1` talks 20 calls from `L1`, and 19 calls from `L2`

`X2` talks 15 calls from `L3`

`X3` talks 10 calls from `L4`

my query will return the following output:

`X1`

`X1`

`X2`

it must return :

`X1`

`X2`

`X3`

how to modify the query to not return duplicate name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery must GROUP BY on SUB_ID (not on LINE_FROM). This will provide the total calls of a subscriber and not the top line calls.

In other words move the join in the subquery and group and order by SUB_ID.

DISTINCT in the main query is too late, you will get no duplicates but less results.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding the DISTINCT keyword to the SELECT query at the bottom?

Something like this:

```
with TEMPRESULT AS 
(
select * from 
(
  select CALLS.LINE_FROM , count(*) totalcount
  from CALLS
  where (((END_DATE_CALL-START_DATE_DATE)*24*60*60)<=60 and to_char(S_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')='2015-12-12') 
  group by CALLS.LINE_FROM
  order by totalcount DESC
) 
where rownum <= 3
) 
select DISTINCT F_NAME,L_NAME
from TEMPRESULT
inner join SUBSCRIBERS_LINES on TEMPRESULT.LINE_FROM = SUBSCRIBERS_LINES.line_id
inner join SUBSCRIBERS on SUBSCRIBERS_LINES.SUB_ID = SUBSCRIBERS.SUB_ID;
```

In theory (I haven't tested it by creating this database) this should show:

X1

X2

X3

Comment: no it will not work, because the sub-query only return first 3 rows & with distinct it will show only top 2 results not top 3 results!

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this
(T represents the result from your query)

```
WITH t AS
  (SELECT 1 id, 'x1' subscriber, 'l1' line FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'x1', 'l1' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'x1', 'l1' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'x1', 'l2' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'x1', 'l2' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'x1', 'l2' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'x1', 'l2' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 'x2', 'l3' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 'x2', 'l3' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 'x3', 'l4' FROM dual
  ),
  t1 AS
  (SELECT COUNT(subscriber) totalcount,
    line,
    MAX(subscriber) keep (dense_rank last
  ORDER BY line ) subscribers
  FROM t
  GROUP BY line
  ORDER BY 1 DESC
  )
SELECT subscribers,
  listagg(line
  ||' had '
  || totalcount
  || ' calls ', ',') within GROUP (
ORDER BY totalcount) AS lines
FROM t1
GROUP BY subscribers
```

the results

```
subscribers       lines
x1                 l1 had 3 calls, l2 had 4 calls
x2                 l3 had 2 calls
x3                 l4 had 1 calls
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and readers need to understand how it once worked.